# I cannot close the modal and dimmer in semantic - using react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to get a modal to close in react, using semantic modal. For some reason, I can get the form to close, but the dimmer remains. I need help.

I have tried $('.ui.modal').modal('hide dimmer') and many number of other things.

Modal is here:

```
export default class AddCamerModal extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <Modal 
            id="add-camera-form" 
            trigger={<Button id="color-0093ee border-color-0093ee" 
            basic 
            icon="video-camera" 
            size="large"></Button>}
         >
            <Header icon='cube' content='New Object' />
            <Modal.Content>
               <AddCameraForm />
            </Modal.Content>
         </Modal>
      )
   }
```

Form is here:

```
export default class AddCameraForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   closeModal() {
      $('.modal').modal('hide');
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <Form size="large">
            <Form.Group widths="equal">
               <Form.Field label='Name' control='input' placeholder='Name' name="name" id="name" required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
               <Button type='submit' className="submit" onClick={this.handleSave}>Save</Button>
               <Button type='deny' className="deny" onClick={this.closeModal}>Cancel</Button>
            </Form.Group>
         </Form>
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass 'open' prop false to your modal. You can do it via state or via props. For example:

```
export default class AddCamerModal extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.closeModal=this.closeModal.bind(this)
      state={ isOpen: true }
   }

   closeModal() {
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen});
     }

   render() {
      return (
         <Modal 
            open={this.props.open}
            id="add-camera-form" 
            trigger={<Button id="color-0093ee border-color-0093ee" 
            basic 
            icon="video-camera" 
            size="large"></Button>}
         >
            <Header icon='cube' content='New Object' />
            <Modal.Content>
               <AddCameraForm closeModal={this.closeModal} />
            </Modal.Content>
         </Modal>
      )
   }
}

export default class AddCameraForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

   }

   render() {
      return (
        <div>
         <Form size="large">
            <Form.Group widths="equal">
               <Form.Field label='Name' control='input' placeholder='Name' name="name" id="name" required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
               <Button type='submit' className="submit" onClick={this.handleSave}>Save</Button>
               <Button type='deny' className="deny" onClick={this.props.closeModal}>Cancel</Button>
            </Form.Group>
         </Form>
        </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to make a couple of adjustments from your code, but you got me on the right track, so thank you from the bottom of my heart. That was killing me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this...

```
export default class AddCamerModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                id="add-camera-form"
                open={this.state.open}
                onClose={e => this.setState({ open: false })}
                trigger={
                    <Button
                        id="color-0093ee border-color-0093ee"
                        basic
                        icon="video-camera"
                        size="large"
                        onClick={e => this.setState({ open: true })}
                    />
                }
            >
                <Header icon="cube" content="New Object" />
                <Modal.Content>
                    <AddCameraForm />
                </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I want to post this just in case someone gets stuck in the same rabbit hole I was in. I had to set the open attribute in the modal, then pass that down to my AddCameraForm through the closeModal prop.

Here's the AddCameraModal:

```
export default class AddCameraModal extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.openModal=this.openModal.bind(this);
      this.closeModal=this.closeModal.bind(this);

      this.state = { isOpen: false }
   }

   openModal() {
      this.setState({isOpen: true})
   }

   closeModal() {
       this.setState({isOpen: false});
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <Modal 
            open={this.state.isOpen}
            id="add-camera-form" 
            trigger={
               <Button id="color-0093ee border-color-0093ee" 
                  basic 
                  icon="video-camera" 
                  size="large" onClick={this.openModal}>
               </Button>
            }
         >
            <Header icon='cube' content='New Object' />
            <Modal.Content>
               <AddCameraForm closeModal={this.closeModal} openModal={this.openModal} />
            </Modal.Content>
         </Modal>
      )
   }
}
```

And here's the button's code from my AddCameraForm class:

```
<Button type='deny' className="cancel" onClick={this.props.closeModal}>Cancel</Button>
```